# Questions around AlwaysOn replication on SQL Server 2016 SP1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to replicate my SQL Server 2016 SP1 production database to an AlwaysOn replication in another database of the same type.

I understand the replication will be read-only, but what happens when users make changes to the source DB?

For example, if I add a view to the source DB, does that view immediately get created in the replication?

What about User permissions, Logins, Stored Procedures, Indexes, even entire tables? If those are created on my source DB, do they instantly replicate over to an AlwaysOn replication?

If these all do replicate, is there anything which *doesn't* replicate over using an AlwaysOn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If these all do replicate, is there anything which doesn't replicate over using an AlwaysOn?

Everything stored in the database is replicated.  Tables, Indexes, Views, Proc, Users, Roles, etc.  Everything that would be included in a Database Backup is replicated.

Everything stored *outside* the database is not replicated.  Logins, SQL Agent Jobs, SSIS Packages, Instance Configuration settings, etc.

Comment: @OP, it's also worth noting that replication is not necessarily instantaneous, even in synchronous replication mode - there is still the log redo latency which can in cases of blocking, show data and changes as being lagged.

Comment: Noted. I expect a few seconds lag, I perhaps should have used a different word than  "instantly" :)